# ELECTRONJS: cant access app in preload script

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a preloadscript and I need to access app. For some reason im getting this error.

[image]

```
const { contextBridge, app} = require('electron');

  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('mainMethods', {
     quit: () => {
        console.log(app.getPath())
     }
})
```